# Bold and Normal textstyle inside a cell in JsPdf autotable (how to use bold and normal text using jsautotable jspdf)

Tags: javascript, arrays, jspdf-autotable, text-styling

I created an array with values from a dynamic table using [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
Then convert it to pdf like this

```
doc.autoTable(vHeader, vData, opt);
doc.save('myTable');
```

Wherein,

> vHeader = header array 
>       vData = data  inside the body cells 
>       opt = styling

My output is this PDF output:

[image: The table]

As you can see in the image, for example, "260.00 /roll", I want to make "260.00" in bold text while leaving " /roll" in regular. Can you help me with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a really good example of a bad question. Please update it to include what you are currently trying along with the specific issues/errors you are getting.

Comment: Hello thank you for saying. I've already updated it. I hope its fine now.

Comment: could you please tell did my answer help?

Comment: I have pasted code here please go through this link.    https://codepen.io/pallamollasai/project/editor/AVPpOK         pdf will be downloaded & check it once.

Comment: Hello. I did copied the whole code you've sent together with the plug in yet the error still occured.

Comment: have you gone through above codepen link . DId you get downloaded pdf?

Comment: I have edited the answer please go through once. Have you gone through codepen link i mentioned above (you can see code inside autoTableText method). ? Add html2canvas once and check please?

Comment: yes i did add html2canvas. i'm trying some other method and i hope i can solve this asap. btw thank you for helping me.

Comment: did you go through codepen link i mentioned(abov)?  did you see the downloaded pdf (you want that only right)?

Comment: Are you using any framework or direclty plain javascript html?

Comment: The pdf output of your code is what output I wanted. I am using native JS and HTML.

Comment: You got pdf throgh codepen? wow atlast it worked?

Comment: If you are facing any error could you please show error with full code? I will try to reproduce in my laptop

Comment: could you plz accept my answer if it works?

Answer (score 2):

After working whole day following code worked to mix both bold & normal text inside a cell.

To download **autotable.js** source code go to through this link.(copy the whole code inside file called  **autoTableJSpdf.js**)

To download **html2canvas(1.0.0-alpha.11)** source code go through this link and download "html2canvas.js" file and paste it inside your folder & include it in script. (No need to change this file.)

[html2canvas 1.0.0 alpha.11](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha.11)

[download autotablejs 3.2.2](https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.2.2/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js)

I am taking my own data for reference.

** whole html & javscript code **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script> // download source code & paste inside file called "html2canvas.js"

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="autoTableJSpdf.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <!-- this html is not necessary -->
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div id='doc'>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <div class="first-page">
        <h1>bond</h1>
        <img src="1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="second-page">
        <img src="2.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="saveDoc()">click</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var doc = new jsPDF();
        // You can use html:
        // doc.autoTable({html: '#my-table'});

        // Or JavaScript:
        var header = ["qty","particular","luzon","trading","arrow"];
        //var data = [];
        //var i=0;
        doc.autoTable({
            willDrawCell: (data) => {


                if(data.section==='body') {
                    if(data.row.index===0 && data.column.index ===2) {

                        var endIndex = data.cell.raw.indexOf('/');
                        var boldText = data.cell.raw.substring(0,endIndex);
                        var normalText = data.cell.raw.substring(endIndex);
                        console.log("boldText is  "+boldText+"  normalText is  "+normalText);
                        // data.cell.raw = '<b>'+boldText+'</b>'+normalText;

                        data.cell.text = '<b>'+boldText+'</b>'+normalText;

                        console.log("after data cell iss  ");
                        console.log(data.cell.raw);

                        console.log('<b>'+boldText+'</b>'+normalText);

                    }
                }

            },

           // columnStyles: {0: {halign: 'center', fillColor: [0, 255, 0]}},
            head: [header],
            body: [
                ['5 tube','electrical','260.00 /roll','290.00 ,Armark1','230.00,crorocdile'],
                ['6 tube','electrical1','261.00 /roll','291.00 ,Armark11','231.00,crorocdile']

            ]
        });




        console.log("i is  "+i);
        doc.save('table.pdf');

     </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

After writing above code you need to make change inside (**autoTableJSpdf.js** which you downloaded ) **jsPDF.API.autoTableText** method like below. just add like below.

```
// dont change any code 
// method name jsPDF.API.autoTableText  
if (typeof x !== 'number' || typeof y !== 'number') { // this will already there
    console.error('The x and y parameters are required. Missing for text: ', text);
}
// new code to add
if (/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(text)) { // you need to add this whole if code 
    // text = text.join(' ');
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = text;
    text = div.innerHTML;
    this.fromHTML('<div style=" font-size: 15px; ">' + text + '</div>', x, y, { // y coord
        'width': 120
    });
    return this;
}
// remaining code
```

Following links might help.

[how to mix both bold & normal html  github](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/364)

Comment: hello @PALLAMOLLA it gave me an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'API' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:1894)'