# How can I make jsPDF-AutoTable in Angular interpret <b> tags when copying an HTML table?

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

The tags are inside the cells as plain text. How can I make jsPDF-AutoTable interpret them and change only what is inside the tags? The only thing I have managed to do is to change the style of the whole cell.

[For example, in the table of this image, I want 'Lorem ipsum' to be bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylh2d.png)

I am creating the tables with this method:

```
addTable(doc: jsPDF, table: any, posY: number): void {
  return autoTable(doc,{
    html: table,
    useCss: true,
    startY: posY,
    rowPageBreak: 'avoid'
  });
}
```

And I get the tables with this:

```
const tableIds = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Table"]');
...
for (let i = 0; i < tableIds.length; i++) {
  ...
  this.utils.addTable(doc, tableIds[i], posY);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, as I know there is no simple solution for this. You need either to handle the text yourself, for example with a custom `drawCell` function, or modify the autotable source code (like [done here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427546/bold-and-normal-textstyle-inside-a-cell-in-jspdf-autotable-how-to-use-bold-and) - caution: I haven't tested this code, but I already made some custom changes to jsPDF, it's not that hard)